# Adding more details to FriendPickerFragment in android app

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I want to use the FriendPickerFragment but instead of showing only the picture and name i would like to add more details like where he working? where he live?

Do you know how i can do it? and explain? or point me to example.
I look in the web to solution and didn't find something.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Facebook's `FriendPickerFragment` does not provide any methods to customize information it presents. The most reasonable solution is to create your own fragment with `ListView`. You should also create list's adapter feeded with `GraphUser` objects representing user's friends. List of friends can be obtained from server by using `Request.executeMyFriendsRequestAsync(Session, com.facebook.Request.GraphUserListCallback)` method.